# Python function returns different values when executed from a Bash script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, exit-code

I have a sample Python file "Test_exit.py":

```
import os

def test_exit():
    print('Line 1.\n')
    print('Line 2.\n')
    exit (17)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_exit()
```

When I execute it using Python, it works as expected:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-235:~$ python3 Test_exit.py
Line 1.

Line 2.
```

When I check the returned error code, it does print "17" as expected:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-235:~$ echo $?
17
```

However, things work different when I execute the same Python file from a Bash script "Test_exit.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash

    Exit_code=$(python3 Test_exit.py)
    echo $Exit_code
```

I would expect it to echo "17", but it doesn't:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-235:~$ ./Test_exit.sh
Line 1. Line 2.
```

Not only it doesn't echo "17", but now the two lines are printed without a new line...

If I replace `exit (17)` with `sys.exit (17)`, then nothing is printed, not even the 2 lines in a single line...

What's wrong with my code? Does `exit` cause not only Python to exist, but Bash script as well?
And why are strings printed differently depending on how Python is called?

**EDIT**

For future reference, here is the script that works well, as advised by @choroba:

```
#!/bin/bash

    output=$(python3 Test_exit.py)
    Exit_code=$?
    echo "$Exit_code"
    echo "$output"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command substitution `$(...)` doesn't return the exit code, it captures the output. Use `$?` to check the exit code.

```
output=$(python3 Test_exit.py)
exit_code=$?
```

To get the exact output, you need to double quote the variable:

```
echo "$Exit_code"
```

Without quotes, the variable is expanded and undergoes word-splitting, so each word in the output is treated as a separate argument to `echo` which leads to reduction of whitespace to single spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much @choroba for a quick and useful answer!